# Binary string to decimal converting

Tags: c, binary, type-conversion, decimal

I try to convert binary string to decimal and use below function.

It works as expected as long as the binary string is 32bit long. But it doesn't produce correct results after that. For example the binary string which is commented not working.

Can anyone help me find the issue?

```
#include <stdio.h>

// converts binary string to integer decimal number
size_t strBinaryToDecimal(char* s)
{
    char        c;
    char   *p = s;
    size_t  r = 0;

    while (p && *p)
    {
        c = *p++;

        if      ( c == '0' ) { r = (r<<1)     ; } // shift 1 bit left and add 0
        else if ( c == '1' ) { r = (r<<1) + 1 ; } // shift 1 bit left and add 1
        else                 { break          ; } // bail on invalid character
    }
    return (size_t)r;
}

int main(void)
{
    char reading[32] = "10011001100110011001100110011001";
    // char reading[33] = "100110011001100110011001100110011"; // not working correctly

    printf("Binary: %s\n", reading);
    printf("Decimal: %zu\n", strBinaryToDecimal(reading));

  return 0;
}
```

I tried to change the decimal integer type to size_t. But it didn't work.

Comment: `reading` can not hold a string of length 32. It can only hold 31 characters. If you initialize with 32 characters, the terminating 0 byte is missing and the result is not a string. You mustn't pass this to any function expecting a string. As you do pass it, you are invoking undefined behaviour which may seem to work well while it is still broken. Change it to `reading[33]` for the active code and `reading[34]` for the code in comment. Or just remove size from definition.

Comment: O/T no need to cast, can just do `return r;`, `r` is already a `size_t` type.

Comment: no advantage here in specifying the size yourself,, in fact that opens the door for problems as you've demonstrated. Just do `char reading[] = "10011...";` (or `char* reading = "..."` since you're not modifying `reading`) and the compiler will create the correct size for you, including the NUL terminator.

Comment: With a 32-bit compiler `size_t` is likely to be 32 bits and your binary string with 33 bits won't work anyway. I suggest you use `uint64_t` to be portable.

Comment: Gerhadh and yano thank you. Edited accordingly, but the problem exists.

Comment: Yeah as Weather Vane pointed out, what does `sizeof(size_t)` return?

Comment: Aside: please don't update the code to keep pace with comments: SO isn't a rolling tutorial.

Comment: Another remark: I guess this is an assignment, but in practice, your never write such a function yourself (unless you have, in writing, with a proper technical analysis of "why", a reason for reinventing the wheel the twelfth millionth time) but use the standard library's `strtoull` (or potentially a different even more specifically optimized number parser library).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Computers are quite good in computations you do not need to calculate the size needed for the string yourself. Your one is too short and does not contain a null terminating character and it is undefined behaviour
2. `size_t` has a specific function in C
3. use `const` if you do not change parameters or variables
4. You do not need to check for NULL pointer at every iteration

```
unsigned long long strBinaryToDecimal(const char* p)
{
    unsigned long long result = 0;
    if(p)
        while(*p)
        {
            result <<= 1;
            if(*p == '0' || *p == '1') result += *p == '1';
            else return -1; //indicate error
            p++;
        }
    return result;
}

int main(void)
{
    char reading[] = "10011001100110011001100110011001";

    printf("Binary: %s\n", reading);
    printf("Decimal: %llu\n", strBinaryToDecimal(reading));
}
```

Comment: My main issue was not using "unsigned long long", I can see now. Thank you.